# Traverse with Powershell Output when stored as an Object

Tags: html, powershell, email, output, html-email

I have this command to get CLuster information from my servers:

```
$DBServers = "DC2TSCDB01"
$DBObject = `
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $DBServers {
        Import-Module FailoverClusters
        Get-ClusterGroup `
        | Where-Object {$_.Name -Like 'SQL Server*'} `
        | Sort-Object Name `
        | Format-Table `
        | out-string
}
$DBObject

Name                     OwnerNode  State
----                     ---------  -----
SQL Server (FS)          DC2TSCdb02 Online
SQL Server (GG)          DC2TSCdb02 Online
SQL Server (RQ)          DC2TSCdb02 Online
SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) DC2TSCdb01 Online
```

How can I traverse to each values while printing so that I can format it as html output?

Comment: before we get too far, have you tried piping your $DBObject into ConvertTo-HTML?  That may do the trick for you.

Comment: @BryceMcDonald he really can't because he piped his output to Out-String so $DBObject isn't really an object, but a string object.

Comment: Ah!  Good catch @ShawnEsterman - I didn't catch that when I skimmed.  Good answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$DBServers = "DC2TSCDB01"
$DBObject = `
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $DBServers {
        Import-Module FailoverClusters
        Get-ClusterGroup `
        | Where-Object {$_.Name -Like 'SQL Server*'} `
        | Sort-Object Name
}

# Convert to table for console
$DBObject | Format-Table -AutoSize

# Convert to HTML table with all elements
$DBOject | ConvertTo-Html

# Convert to HTML table with just <table> elements
$DBObject | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
```